# Statically Link OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I would like to compile a C++ program that uses openCV statically, so that I can use it on other computers without having to install openCV.

I compiled openCV 2.4.5 with following flags in order to get static libraries and to install it besides my main installation which is version 3.1.

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt/openCV_2_4_5 -D WITH_FFMPEG=OFF -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=NO ..

ls /opt/openCV_2_4_5/lib
libopencv_calib3d.a     libopencv_flann.a    libopencv_legacy.a     libopencv_photo.a      libopencv_video.a
libopencv_contrib.a     libopencv_gpu.a      libopencv_ml.a         libopencv_stitching.a  libopencv_videostab.a
libopencv_core.a        libopencv_highgui.a  libopencv_nonfree.a    libopencv_superres.a   pkgconfig
libopencv_features2d.a  libopencv_imgproc.a  libopencv_objdetect.a  libopencv_ts.a         python2.7
```

After installing, I tried to compile a c++ program for face detection like this:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -L/opt/openCV_2_4_5/lib -I/opt/openCV_2_4_5/include -o ex2 ex2.cpp -L. -lpthread -lz -lopencv_stitching -lopencv_superres -lopencv_videostab -lopencv_aruco -lopencv_bgsegm -lopencv_bioinspired -lopencv_ccalib -lopencv_dnn -lopencv_dpm -lopencv_fuzzy -lopencv_line_descriptor -lopencv_optflow -lopencv_plot -lopencv_reg -lopencv_saliency -lopencv_stereo -lopencv_structured_light -lopencv_rgbd -lopencv_surface_matching -lopencv_tracking -lopencv_datasets -lopencv_text -lopencv_face -lopencv_xfeatures2d -lopencv_shape -lopencv_video -lopencv_ximgproc -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_flann -lopencv_xobjdetect -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_ml -lopencv_xphoto -lopencv_videoio -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_photo -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_core
```

From that I got the error:

```
/tmp/cct4prBn.o: In function `main':
ex2.cpp:(.text+0x141): undefined reference to `cv::imread(std::string const&, int)'
ex2.cpp:(.text+0x2bc): undefined reference to `cv::imread(std::string const&, int)'
ex2.cpp:(.text+0x4f3): undefined reference to `cv::imwrite(std::string const&, cv::_InputArray const&, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > const&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make_2_4_5:9: recipe for target 'ex2' failed
make: *** [ex2] Error 1
```

I used the same library flags as my installation of OpenCV 3.1 has. I got them from:

```
pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv
```

The -L and -I flags point to the openCV 2.4.5 installation in the /opt directory.

Why doesn't it compile? All OpenCV libraries are listed in the section where the static libraries should be.

Answer (score 1):

In OpenCV 2 I believe `cv::imread()` and `cv::imwrite()` are in the `highgui` library. In OpenCV 3 they were moved to the `imgcodecs` library.  Try adding:

```
-lopencv_highgui
```

to your command line.

Comment: Thanks, no I get the error:
/usr/bin/ld: /opt/openCV_2_4_5/lib/libopencv_highgui.a(window_gtk.cpp.o): undefined reference to symbol 'gtk_range_get_value'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: I have to add every library manually (for jpg, png, tiff...) is there a smarter way?

Comment: It looks like your OpenCV 2.4.5 was compiled with support for GTK+, but you aren't linking with the GTK+ library.  GTK+ is an optional component which gives richer GUI capability than OpenCV highgui otherwise has.  3 possible solutions are: (1) find and link the correct GTK+ library (assuming you have GTK installed); (2) try linking the other example programs, which may not have a dependency on GTK+; (3) recompile OpenCV from source, without support for GTK+.  I don't use GTK+, so I can't really help further, sorry.

Comment: When I add gtk+, it asks for the next library. In that fashion i added about 10  different libraries. Can g++ detect it automatically?

Comment: I don't know, sorry. I use MSVC++ mostly, and dependencies there seem less of a problem.